# how to enable checkbox after validating email?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know how to enable the check box only when the email is validated as valid.
I was able to make the checkbox enabled only if all the fields were filled, but I wanted it to be disabled until the email was valid.

> HTML

```
  <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputNome" class="col-lg-2 control-label" ng-class="{'text-white': invertTextColor}">Nome</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNome" name="inputNome" placeholder="Nome"
                                   ng-class="{'text-white': invertTextColor}" ng-model="user" required onkeyup="changeDetected()"/>

                            <div ng-messages="guestForm.inputNome.$error" style="color:red" role="alert" ng-show="formSubmitted">
                                <div ng-message="required">É necessário um nome.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <label for="inputCPF" class="col-lg-2 control-label" ng-class="{'text-white': invertTextColor}">CPF</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCPF" name="inputCPF" placeholder="CPF" ng-class="{'text-white': invertTextColor}" ng-model="cpf" maxlength="11" required onkeyup="changeDetected()"/>
                            <div ng-messages="guestForm.inputCPF.$error" style="color:red" role="alert" ng-show="formSubmitted">
                                <div ng-message="required">É necessário um CPF.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <label for="inputPhone" class="col-lg-2 control-label" ng-class="{'text-white': invertTextColor}">Telefone</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" name="inputPhone" placeholder="(11)999999999" ng-class="{'text-white': invertTextColor}" ng-model="phone" maxlength="11" required onkeyup="changeDetected()"/>
                            <div ng-messages="guestForm.inputPhone.$error" style="color:red" role="alert" ng-show="formSubmitted">
                                <div ng-message="required">É necessário um Telefone.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label" ng-class="{'text-white': invertTextColor}">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Email"
                                   ng-class="{'text-white': invertTextColor}" ng-model="email" required onkeyup="changeDetected()"/>

                            <div ng-messages="guestForm.inputEmail.$error" style="color:red" role="alert">
                                <div ng-message="email">É necessário um e-mail válido.</div>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-messages="guestForm.inputEmail.$error" style="color:red" role="alert" ng-show="formSubmitted">
                                <div ng-message="required">É necessário um e-mail.</div>
                                <div ng-message="email">É necessário um e-mail válido.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
```

> JavaScript

```
 function changeDetected(){
  name = $('#inputNome').val()
  cpf = $('#inputCPF').val()
  phone = $('#inputPhone').val();
  email = $('#inputEmail').val();


  if ((name.length > 0) && (cpf.length > 0) && (phone.length > 0) && (email.length > 0)) {
    $('#eula').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {

    $('#eula').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery to retrieve values with AngularJS? Why not use built [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) and/or [ngMinLength](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMinlength)? This would expose various form validation utilties that you could use in any of these methods that are in sync with the controller's $scope. Using jQuery to retrieve those values and manipulate DOM values defeats the entire purpose of AngularJS. Look at this [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) on forms before continuing.

Comment: Make a function, whose entire purpose is to validate the E-mail, and the E-mail only and make a logic around that. Simply separate your validation logic a bit. Or are you asking *"How to validate"* an E-mail? In that case, use *regular expression(s)*. Right now all of your validation is clustered into one validation, which you can do too, but you'll have to change your `if else` logic to fit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `if` logic to :

```
function validateEmail(email){
        var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
        return re.test(email);
    }
if (((email.length > 0) && validateEmail(email)) && ((name.length > 0) && (cpf.length > 0) && (phone.length > 0))) {
    $('#eula').removeAttr('disabled');
} else {
    $('#eula').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Comment: did not work.
I would like the checkbox to be enabled only when the email was valid.

Comment: do you want to check for a valid email meaning - a dot symbol and an @ ?

Comment: Yes, but leave the checkbox disabled until you perform this validation.

Comment: I tested with the code above but even putting the valid email to checkbox is still disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery.validate, you should probably get something to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This can and absolutely should be done entirely without jQuery and entirely with AngularJS built in directives. Using [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) in combination with [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled), you can check whether form elements are `$valid`/`$invalid` based validation attributes such as `required` and `minLength` on your input elements. This approach will respond in realtime to changes in the controller's $scope and AngularJS lifecycle without needing to do manual DOM manipulation with jQuery. This would be inline with the AngularJS approach to [forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms). It would also make it testable. I've provided a small sample as you should be able to use this sample to apply to your remaining elements and logic.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="inputNome" id="inputNome" ng-model="inputNome" required />
<input type="text" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" ng-model="inputEmail" required />
<input type="checkbox" name="eula" id="eula" ng-disabled="!isEnabled(form)" />
```

Controller:

```
$scope.isEnabled = function(form) {
  return !form.email.$invalid && !form.inputNome.$invalid;
}
```

You can check for validity of any input by using properties on any input in a named form. The values as JSON comes out to something like the following. Notice, you check a number of properties including whether the form control has been touched, whether it's valid/invalid, and more. Errors are provided in object form on the `$error` property.

```
{ "$viewValue": "", "$modelValue": "", "$validators": {}, "$asyncValidators": {}, "$parsers": [], "$formatters": [ null ], "$viewChangeListeners": [], "$untouched": true, "$touched": false, "$pristine": true, "$dirty": false, "$valid": false, "$invalid": true, "$error": { "required": true }, "$name": "email", "$options": null }
```

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/axd3qscUMPGy56scQARE?p=preview) to demonstrate the functionality. Notice the checkbox is disabled until both inputs become valid. You can do this with any number of elements and with any validations such as minimum length.

Answer (score 0):

Your only validation for the E-mail right now is to check whether it contains more than 1 entry (basically to see whether it's empty or not). If you want a full E-mail validation, you'd probably also want a *regular expression* as well to check if the E-mail fits the normal syntax of an actual E-mail.

However, if everything is okay, and you just want the validation you already have, but want the checkbox logic to revolve solely around the E-mail validation, all you have to do is re-construct your `if else` logic a bit.

Example:

```
function changeDetected() {
    name = $('#inputNome').val()
    cpf = $('#inputCPF').val()
    phone = $('#inputPhone').val();
    email = $('#inputEmail').val();

    if(email.length > 0) {
        $('#eula').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('#eula').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

    if ((name.length > 0) && (cpf.length > 0) && (phone.length > 0)) {
        //The rest of your validation logic
    }
}
```